# Pythonic way of returning None if input itself is None?

Tags: python

What's the best way to write a *null-check* in Python? `Try-Except` blocks, `if` blocks...?

Given a function that returns `None` if the input is `None`, a valid input, what's the best approach to deal with this situation? Take this function for example:

```
def urlify(path):
    if path is None:
        return None

    return "<a href=\"{0!s}\">{0!s}</a>".format(path)
```

Comment: You could do `return path and "<a href=\"{0!s}\">{0!s}</a>".format(path)`

Comment: I'd avoid using `str.format()` to generate HTML instead of a proper sanitizing template engine. Too many security holes to leave open.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Will do, this was a quick example for a Jinja2 extension filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a *ternary operator* with the return statement to return None if path is None or return something else otherwise.

```
def urlify(path):
    return path if path is None else "<a href=\"{0!s}\">{0!s}</a>".format(path)
```

However considering functions return None by default, you can simply do:

```
def urlify(path):
    if path is not None:
        return "<a href=\"{0!s}\">{0!s}</a>".format(path)
```

Or as vaultah suggested in the comments, you could also short-circuit using `and`.

Comment: I like the first suggestion in cases the return value is brief, otherwise it ends up taking too much horizontal space.

The latter is the one I like the most, but is not as obvious that it returns `None`.

I don't really understand short-circuiting using `and`, I can't comment on his @vaultah suggested.

Comment: I personally prefer the short-circuit `and`, but these choices allow empty strings/False/etc to be passed as well.  I suppose it depends on how flexible OP'd like their function to be.

Comment: @Alxe `(a and b) is (a if not a else b)`